# History of preservation theorems in forcing theory

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview, forcing

For my honours thesis, I am studying a general preservation theorem using a framework provided by Shelah. I am mainly concerned about revised countable support iteration of $\dot{S}$-semiproper forcing notions, for a specific class of $\dot{S}$. For the introduction to my paper, I wish to include a historical background of the study of preservation theorems.

A preservation theorem is generally a statement of the form:
"If $\bar{Q}$ is an X iteration with all iterands (here it depends on how you define an iterand) having property $P$, then $lim(\bar{Q})$ has property $P$."
In this case, we say property $P$ is preserved under $X$ iteration.

I know one of the landmarks is Shelah's prove of the preservation of $``^{\omega}{\omega}$-bounding + properness$"$ under CS iteration. Also, there are a number of preservation theorems under various iterations investigated by Shelah in the 1980s-1990s, most of which can be found in his book *Proper and Improper Forcing*. But what are the works leading up to Shelah's contributions? I hope to put together a chronology of the important preservation theorems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roslanowski has recorded some of Shelah's recollections about the prehistory of proper forcing here http://www.unomaha.edu/logic/papers/essay.pdf

Comment: I think the oldest preservation theorem is the preservation of the countable chain condition under finite-support iteration.  (Or is that too primitive for your survey?)

Comment: @Ashutosh: That is an interesting read. Thanks.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah yes. I even forgot about it. I can throw in Baumgartner's preservation of Axiom A forcing too, for good measure. Do you know who first got that ccc is preserved under FS iteration? Was it in Solovay and Tennenbaum?

Comment: Yes, the preservation of ccc in finite-support iterations was, as far as I know, first proved in the Solovay-Tennenbaum paper on the consistency of Souslin's Hypothesis.

Comment: Also maybe Laver's paper "On the consistency of Borel's conjecture" is the first paper presenting a preservation theorem for countable support iterations (for a very special case of just adding Laver reals iteratively).

Comment: Also Magidor (in "How large is the first strongly compact cardinal? or A study on identity crises. ") has proved the first result about preservation of Prikry property under suitable iteration of Prikry type forcings.

Comment: @Golshani: Thanks, I will look those up.